# Jquery slideshow disable autoplay

Tags: jquery, wordpress

hello am trying to disable this slideshow from moving automatically . can u please help ? 
i tried almost everything i could do but i couldnt. this is a part of functions.php file where it include the script as i hope i placed the correct code

```
<div id="banner" class="blog-carousel-v2">

                    <script>

                        jQuery(document).ready(
                        function() {  
                          jQuery(".blog-carousel-v2 .sliderpagination").niceScroll({
                            cursorwidth : 10,
                            cursorcolor :"#616161",
                            autohidemode:false,
                            cursorborder : '2px solid #131313',
                            railoffset:true,
                            cursorborderradius : 0,
                            background: "#161616"
                          });

                        });
                        </script>
                    <?php
                    $slider_pagination = array();
                        echo '<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
                            data-cycle-fx=fade
                            data-cycle-timeout=0
                            data-cycle-auto-height=container
                            data-cycle-slides="article"

                            data-cycle-random=false
                            data-cycle-pager="#home-banner-pager"
                            data-cycle-pager-template="">';
                            $counter_slideshow=0;
                        while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
                            $counter_slideshow++;
                            $image_url_full = px_get_post_img_src($post->ID, '810' ,'410');
                            if($image_url_full <> ''){
                            $slider_pagination[] = get_the_title();
                            ?>
                                <article class="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                                    <?php if($image_url_full <> ''){?><img src="<?php echo $image_url_full;?>" alt=""><?php }?>

                                           <div class="caption">
                                                <?php 
                                                    $rating = px_user_rating_display('blog-carousel-v2'.$counter_slideshow);
                                                    if(isset($rating) && $rating <> ''){
                                                        ?>
                                                        <div class="heading-color cs-rating-heading">
                                                            <?php  echo $rating;?>
                                                        </div>
                                                <?php }?>
                                                <div class="text">
                                                    <?php 
                                                    $before_cat = '<span> ';
                                                    $categories_list = get_the_term_list ( get_the_id(), 'category', $before_cat, ', ', '</span>' );
                                                    if ( $categories_list ){
                                                        printf( __( '%1$s', 'Media News'),$categories_list );
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( strlen(get_the_title()) > 50){echo get_the_title();} else { the_title();} if ( strlen(get_the_title()) > 50) echo get_the_title();?></a></h2>
                                                    <?php px_posted_on(false,false,true,true,false,false);?>

                                                </div>
                                           </div> 
                                </article>
                            <?php
                            }
                        endwhile;
            echo '</div>';

            if(is_array($slider_pagination) && count($slider_pagination)>0){
                $pagination_no = 0;
                echo '<div class="sliderpagination">
                    <ul id="home-banner-pager" class="banner-pager">';
                        while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
                            $counter_slideshow++;
                            $image_small_full = px_get_post_img_src($post->ID, '150' ,'150');
                            if($image_small_full <> ''){
                                echo '<li>
                                <figure><img src="'.$image_small_full.'" alt=""></figure>';
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="text">
                                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( strlen(get_the_title()) > 50){echo get_the_title();} else { the_title();} if ( strlen(get_the_title()) > 50) echo  "...";?></a></h2>
                                    <?php
                                    px_posted_on(false,false,true,true,true,false);
                                    ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                echo '</li>';
                            }
                    endwhile;
                    echo '</ul></div>';
            }
        px_enqueue_cycle_script();
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the $counter_slideshow variable could be where your problem lies.

If you set a condition to only increment it when you want it to go to the next slide then it should not advance to the next slide.

Try setting a flag early on before the you increment the $counter_slideshow variable:

```
     //set flag to turn slide show on or off 1 = on  0 = off
     $slideShowOn = 0;
```

Then you can put a check in your while loop similar to this:

```
      //if the $slideShowOn equals 1 or on
      if($slideShowOn === 1){//begin if then else

      //increment the counter
       $counter_slideshow++;

      }
      else{

       //do something if the slideShowOn variable doesn't equal 1

     }//end if then else
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a live preview so I can help debug your script?